# JTable with a ScrollPane misbehaving

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JPanel` component with a `JTable` inside of it.  When I run the code as it's written below, the table renders and updates correctly.  As soon as I try to use the `scrollPane` approach, the table does not render at all.  Can anyone explain to me why this is?

```
    private static class GameHistoryPanel extends JPanel {

        private DataModel model;
        private JTable table;
        private int currentRow;
        private int currentColumn;
        private final Dimension HISTORY_PANEL_DIMENSION = new Dimension(190,460);


        public GameHistoryPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.model = new DataModel();
            this.table = new JTable(model);
            this.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//            scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
//            this.add(scrollPane);
            setPreferredSize(HISTORY_PANEL_DIMENSION);
            this.currentRow = 0;
            this.currentColumn = 0;
        }

        public void increment(Board board, Move move) {
            model.setValueAt(move, currentRow, currentColumn);
            if(board.currentPlayer().getAlliance() == Alliance.WHITE) {
                currentColumn++;
            } else if (board.currentPlayer().getAlliance() == Alliance.BLACK) {
                currentRow++;
                currentColumn = 0;
            }
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that answered by (@trashgod), everything important bases on your question and code are there,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using a `JTable` as view of a `TableModel` in which each cell exists in one of two states. Visible changes to a cell should result *only* from a change to the model, which may be examined in preparing the cell's [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). In particular, invoking the methods `validate()` and `repaint()` should *not* be required. Their presence suggests that you are altering the view without the model's knowledge, which could explain the anomaly seen.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
this.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: @AmirAfghani, try to setPreferredSize on JScrollPane

Comment: @Amir Afghani then post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), exaclty demonstrated your issue, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JSCrollPane and JTable

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov too fast suggestion, everything without SSCCE are shots to the dark :-)

Comment: Extracting this into an SSCCE is going to be hard - I'll see what I can do.  The strange thing is that the whole panel containing the table is grey.  When it works, the table renders white.

Comment: @Amir Afghani then your personal issue hidden in the rest of your code, everything without SSCCE are shots to the dark,

Comment: @mKorbel I understand - I thought I might have overlooked something easy to see in that section of code that would be easy to spot.

Comment: `panel containing the table is grey` this is about `Background` of `JScrollPane`, required more details

Comment: by default JTable with JScrollPane haven't any issues, something strange, nor bugs

Comment: Using `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` is a (marginally) better alternative is a `JScrollPane`. See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score 1):

This may be stating the obvious, but remember that you can only add a JComponent to a container **once**.

After

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.model = new DataModel();
this.table = new JTable(model);
```

either you

```
this.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// note that table-headers should not be added explicitly
// commented out: this.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

or you

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
this.add(scrollPane);
```

but trying to do both will result in problems.

I recommend using Swingx's JXTable, if at all possible. Much more flexible, and out-of-the-box column sorting and hiding/reordering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but indeed this is obvious.  The former works, the latter does not.  Why shouldn't the table headers be added explicitly?