# JTable inside of ScrollPane only shows up after resize

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

My application's JFrame logic looks like:

```
public Table() {
    super("Chess");
    thisFrame = this;
    tableMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    populateMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(tableMenuBar);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    chessBoard = new Board(new StandardBoardConfigurator());
    gamePanel = new GameHistoryPanel();
    chatPanel = new ChatPanel();
    takenPiecesPanel = new TakenPiecesPanel();
    boardPanel = new BoardPanel(chessBoard);
    gameProgress = 1;
    highlightLegalMoves = true;
    moveLog = new ArrayList<Move>();
    gameOver = false;
    getContentPane().add(takenPiecesPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    getContentPane().add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    getContentPane().add(chatPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // Make sure we have nice window decorations.
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

and the `JPanel` containing the JTable is 'GameHistoryPanel', which has this as it's constructor logic:

```
    public GameHistoryPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.model = new DataModel();
        this.table = new JTable(model);
        this.table.setRowHeight(15);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table.getTableHeader());
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(HISTORY_PANEL_DIMENSION);
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.currentRow = 0;
        this.currentColumn = 0;
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The `GamePanel` has the following update routine which calls `setValueAt` whenever a move is made:

```
    public void increment(final Board board,
                          final Move move) {
        this.model.setValueAt(move, currentRow, currentColumn);
        if(board.currentPlayer().getAlliance() == Alliance.WHITE) {
            currentColumn++;
        } else if (board.currentPlayer().getAlliance() == Alliance.BLACK) {
            currentRow++;
            currentColumn = 0;
        }
    }
```

Upon launching the game, the `GamePanel` is grayed out.  When I resize it *vertically*, it suddenly appears with all of the correct values.  I don't understand why.  I did notice that resizing causes `getValueAt` to be invoked a bunch of times.  Can someone help me understand this?

**EDIT 2**: If I add this line:

```
        this.model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

to increment, it seems to work fine.  I'm wholly confused...

EDIT:  Here is my TableModel class:

```
    private static class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final String[] names = {"White", "Black"};
        private final List<Row> values;

        public DataModel() {
            values = new ArrayList<Row>();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return names.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            final Row currentRow = values.get(row);
            if(col == 0) {
                return currentRow.getWhiteMove();
            } else if (col == 1) {
                return currentRow.getBlackMove();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            final Row currentRow;
            if(values.size() <= row) {
                currentRow = new Row();
                values.add(currentRow);
            } else {
                currentRow = values.get(row);
            }
            if(col == 0) {
                currentRow.setWhiteMove((Move) aValue);
            } else  if(col == 1) {
                currentRow.setBlackMove((Move)aValue);
            }
            this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return Move.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return names[col];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which component you resize to make JTable to appear?

Comment: I'd be happy to point you to my gitrepo if that helps?

Comment: see my answer below. when you resize JFrame then it tries to repaint all its components, so you get JTable updated.

Comment: I suspect that you are not creating/launching your application within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: jtable.update() is what i use

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I wasn't and I just added that, but still same behavior. :(

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `setSize(OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION);
    pack();`  You had not noticed that the JRE is 'ignoring' the `OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION`?

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson, I don't understand your comment.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Which comment?  What don't you understand?  It pays to be specific, since I don't have much patience with vague questions.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about the JRE ignoring the OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION.  This seems like it's a bug in my TableModel somehow, because when I invoke fireTableDataChanged, it appears to work.

Comment: not, not, not please where you lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I add this line, `this.model.fireTableDataChanged()`, to `increment()`, it seems to work fine.

Your implementation of `setValueAt()` in `DataMdel` is flawed in that it may add instances of `Row` to the model, while only invoking `fireTableCellUpdated()` for a single `row` and `col`. You need to  fire the event appropriate to the actual modification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I suspected something like this.  I haven't figured out what needs to be modified yet.  I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as I can sort out how to fix the impl.

Comment: @AmirAfghani: Ping me if you update your question. I've found that creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) makes it easier to study such problems in isolation. You may find it helpful to examine my previous answers in the [tag:JTable] tag, many of which contain relevant comments from user kleopatra.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
.invalidate();
.repaint();
```

on either JPanel, JScrollPane, JTable

My guess is that adding as last lines of `increment()`

```
JTable.invalidate();
JTable.repaint();
```

should be sufficient. If not, please, check for each component.

Comment: @AmirAfghani, I will delete this if proper solution is found. Please, let me know.

Comment: This is not the correct approach, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13863334/230513).